# Handling <html> response data instead of Json, Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

Angular 6 application. Invoking a  web servce that returns html data. Had to display that html data in a div.

This is the sample HTML reponse data from the service.

```
<html>
 <head>
<title>Chart : 180: Abraham, Male, 1 Year(S)</title>
</head>
<frameset border=0 rows="145,*">
  <frame noresize id="t_pan" name="t_pan" src="id=180" scrolling="no">
  <frameset border=0 cols="175,*">
    <frame noresize id="l_pan" name="l_pan" src="id=180">
    <frame noresize id="r_pan" name="r_pan" src="Pt&id=1937181">
  </frameset>
</frameset>
</html>
```

This is how I invoking the actual api that returns HTML data(provided above)

```
getDetailData(url:string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url, {headers :{'Accept': 'text/html', 'responseType': 'text' as 'json'}})
        .map(data => {
            data;            
    });
```

In component invoking the service

```
const url = "http://10.98.12.1:2009/PChart?id=180" ; //hard coded for now.
        this.personService.getDetailData(url).subscribe(res =>{
             console.log(res);

        });
```

**throws exception**

> "error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at
>   JSON.parse () at XMLHtt…, text: "..."

Response :

[image]

**Solution to my problem :**

I was using wrong path, I had solved it by using an iframe and loaded data into that.

Comment: Can you add the sample JSON with the HTML code as the JSON seems wrong in this case.

Comment: Also try to validate your JSON with jsonLint maybe

Comment: @nitin9nair I think that's the point. His web service is not returning JSON.

Comment: Can you verify the response header is correct?

Comment: web service returns an HTML data, not JSON

Answer (score 1):

Set responseType to:

```
'responseType': 'text';
```

and API call will be:

```
const url = "http://10.98.12.1:2009/PChart?id=180" ; //hard coded for now.
this.personService.getDetailData(url).subscribe(res => {
    this.name = res;
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<div [innerHTML]="name"></div>
```

Comment: return this.http.get(url, {headers :{'responseType': 'text'}})
        .map(data => {
            data;            
    }); ... it throws same exception

Comment: getDetailData(url:string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url, {headers :{'Accept': 'text/html', 'responseType': 'text'}})
        .map(data => {
            data;            
    });

Comment: no luck, same error. error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at ....It expects a JSON still.

Comment: getDetailData(url:string): Observable<any> { return this.http.get(url, {headers :{'responseType': 'text'}}) .map(data => { data; }); ...............….try this one

Comment: Have u ever tried with HTML as response instead of XML or json ?

Comment: Please find solution, I hope it help you …… https://stackblitz.com/edit/santosh-angular-show-html-in-div?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts